# Spring boot micro service production Environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment

Let us assume application have 10+ Spring Boot micro service. Which is the best way of deploying in production environment for bellow two options?

1. Using embedded server per service run through the `java -jar xyz.jar`?
2. Using the external application server like (Jboss or Tomcat) service are running on their own ports 
   ?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended approach is using the 1st option because :

1. You can use any of the light weight servers i.e., undertow, etc...
2. You can dockerize it, scale up as needed.
3. Easy to maintain and save time and money.

The 2nd option has some limitations like :

- You are not using spring boot self deploying feature.
- Multiple applications can also be deployed due to which your application may be slower.

Comment: Performance wise which is the best approach? embedded server or external server ?

Comment: It's embedded servers.

Comment: how to deploy the multiple micro-services (running on different ports) in Jboss server?

Answer (score 2):

Generally 1 would be preferable if you are on modern infrastructure, however there is no "best way" to do deployments. Both approaches have trade offs:

1. Gives you better isolation and when implement with containers or PAAS allows for [immutable deployments](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-immutable-infrastructure) which is a big improvement when it comes to testing. The downside is more complicated deployment process that should be automated and higher server resource consumption.
2. Usually simplifies the architecture and is better suited for manual deployment process. If your organization doesn't buy in into [Continuous Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) this approach will be much easier to live with. The downside is that over time application servers on different environments (DEV, QAT, PROD) will usually end up with a different configuration setup making testing so much harder.

Comment: I'd also argue that #1 would allow to easier scale your application because you can just deploy more of your containers for services that require more performance (if your design allows it of course). Not sure that is possible with a single application server.

Comment: if the #1 is giving the performance issue, In the second case, 10 spring boot micro service running their own(10) ports, how can we deploy those in one application server?

Comment: @karthikmuthyam it depends what do you mean by performance. 1. with multiple servers might give you more predictable per-request performance but 2. will have generally lower resource utilization if you accept that per-request performance might be worse. You are comparing apples to oranges, if you want raw performance re-implement the whole thing in assembler.

Comment: @karthikmuthyam wars deployed to the same application servers will be exposed on the same port with different context root. There will be no different ports.

Comment: deploying the multiple micro-services (running on different ports) in Jboss server.how can I go with this approach?